# Getting record row/column which caused error using pandas to_sql

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I am using pandas to_sql to insert records in oracle table. I would like to know which row (and column) caused error when the insert failed. Is there a way to get that particular record which was the source of error?

When I catch the exception

```
except Exception as e:
```

`e` has this object

```
DatabaseError('(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-01722: invalid number')
```

I can know from this that it was an invalid number (a string was passed) to a number column but how do I know which row/column?

Comment: You have to compare your statement, and the types of the elements you need to insert, with the table structure. Without these informations, it's hard to understand which value(s) gives the error

Comment: Oracle will not log an invalid client command anywhere by default; the error is only being returned to your program. Within your exception you will need to have the program tell you what was the last SQL command it tried to execute.